# How to check my LAN for broadcast storm issue and how to eliminate it?

Tags: cisco

How to check my LAN for broadcast storm issue and how to eliminate it???I am Using Cisco 2960 switch.

Comment: You could utilize show interface counters that will give you a table of different packets being processed on each interface. Check the counters. Then use clear counters to reset them. Check counters again and you should see if an interface gets huge amounts of broadcast packets within seconds.

Comment: You can also use this: show interface | include (.*Ethernet)|(.*broadcast) - this should give a nicely output with broadcasts on each interface on the switch.

Comment: Lastly setup storm-control to help you find the actual port with broadcast storm on it. Use command on interface config: storm-control broadcast level 5.00 2.00 - sets the miximum broadcast to 5% of the interface speed. Set lower if you want, but that is best practice from Cisco. If an interface goes above this, the switch will apply a filter to the interface and write it in the log.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up storm-control on your switch will allow the switch to enable a filter if a broadcast storm occurs on a user access port. It will write in the log, that the filter has been applied and only remove it if it falls below the configured falling threshold. Use the following command to enable it on an interface:

```
Switch# configure terminal
Switch(config)# interface fastEthernet0/1
Switch(config-if)# storm-control broadcast level 5.00 2.00
Switch(config-if)# end
Switch# write memory
Building configuration...
[OK]

5.00 = if broadcast traffic goes above this percentage, filter.
2.00 = if broadcast falls below this percentage, remove filter.
```

Now check the log by using the command show logging and see if a filter gets applied to the interface.

Depending on what actually made or make the broadcast storm happen, the first thing i would do is remove the connection on the port, where the storm is detected and start by checking the physical setup. Could it be a loop on your network? Faulty NIC? Loop through a PC to wireless?

Most common, in my opinion, is an unmanaged switch connected to the same switch in two different ports creating the loop.

Comment: thakyou Guys hope this will solve the issue